# Script running in crontab reporting database missing error when manually running it doesn't cause the issue

Tags: database, perl, sqlite, cron

I have a script that I run manually every hour in my Laravel that's under this path:

```
/var/www/name/storage/scripts/getListOfClassesFromSubjects.pl
```

What I normally do is, I cd to `/scripts/`, and I manually run:

```
./getListOfClassesFromSubjects.pl
```

And the script works fine.

Today, I setup a crontab to automate this (obviously).

```
0,30 * * * * /var/www/name/storage/scripts/getListOfClassesFromSubjects.pl  >> /var/www/name/storage/logs/schedulizer.log 2>&1
```

Within my logs are this:

```
DBD::SQLite::db prepare failed: no such table: subject_urls at /var/www/loop/storage/scripts/getListOfClassesFromSubjects.pl line 56.
```

Which is an anomaly because when I run the script manually, it's fine.

This is my database's permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     11750400 Aug  4 12:30 database.sqlite
```

So I'm thinking this is the issue with the rwx permissions, so I changed the DB to 755:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11750400 Aug  4 12:30 database.sqlite
```

Still the same issue

Answer (score 3):

For the path to the database, your code uses a relative path that assumes the current directory is the directory in which the script resides. It is not.

Instead of

```
"../database.sqlite"
```

use

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
"$RealBin/../database.sqlite"
```

or

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
chdir($RealBin);
"../database.sqlite"
```

Comment: This is the particular offending line: `my $dbFile = '../database.sqlite';` (the DB is a parent up). Out of curiosity, why would running it manually work, but running it through crontab not?

Comment: Adjusted accordingly. It has nothing to do with manual vs cron; as I explained, it's due to differences in the current work directory. Do `cd /` before doing `/var/www/name/storage/scripts/getListOfClassesFromSubjects.pl  >> /var/www/name/storage/logs/schedulizer.log 2>&1` from the shell, and it will fail there too, and for the same reason.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Out of curiosity, why is this happening in crontab and not when I manually run it?

Comment: I'm not going to explain a third time.

Comment: Blah, I didn't see the explanation. I understand now.